# Are there Sentinel crop labeled datasets available?

Tags: sentinel-2, feature-dataset, machine-learning

I am starting a project where I am going to use Sentinel-2 imagery and machine learning for detecting sugarcane and coffee. In order to train the algorithm I would need labeled sentinel datasets. I've found EuroSat which is a labeled dataset for different land cover classes. I have also found the Brazilian Coffee Scenes Dataset. Is there a similar dataset for sugarcane, coffee and other crops with Sentinel?